# UI library (grid View, Metro style)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, gridview, user-interface

I wanted to know if there is a open source UI library in objective c for grid view like in ted.com or tile.js which is also an open source library for metro style UI used in apps like pulse.me.

Basically I want a grid view with cells of different sizes! I want to make something it on iOS for both iPad and iPhone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 6.0 your best choice would be [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205).

Comment: Maybe [BDDynamicGridViewController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/bddynamicgridviewcontroller) or [TMQuiltView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tmquiltview).

Comment: That operating system is still under NDA.

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` is available in **Available in iOS 6.0 and later** and therefore cannot be used if you want to support earlier version. 
And as per your requirement you need to display a **GridView**

So to support earlier versions and get other cool features you can use other libraries here are some of the options:

1) [KKGridView](https://github.com/kolinkrewinkel/KKGridView)

2) [UIGridView](https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView)

3) [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)

4) [NRGridView](https://github.com/ldesroziers/NRGridView)

5) [MMGridView](https://github.com/provideal/MMGridView)

6) [WCGridView](https://github.com/wess/WCGridView)

I am currently using **`AQGridView`** so surely i recommend that as it is the least buggy and its functions are very similar to `UITableView`.

Also that If you are trying to do this without **XIB** it will be little bit difficult for you to handle it but you can create a view controller with Xib file to Create the interface of your choice. [Here is the Video of how it can be done in the best possible way](http://vimeo.com/46408155) by  `Evadne Wu`. And [here](https://github.com/evadne/gridViewNibTest) is the Sample Project